# AnimationEvent is not defined in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, css-animations

I'm trying to mock an `animationEvent` for one of my test in an Angular app and I'm getting an error:

> ReferenceError: AnimationEvent is not defined.

I'm assuming that as this is an experimental feature it won't be available in jsdom in Jest. Does anyone know a way to mock this?

This is the code that is failing

```
dispatchEvent(new AnimationEvent("animationend", { animationName: "slide-down" }));
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

This event will trigger some code in my component and will emit an output event itself, but I want to make sure that this happens when this specific type of event with the `animationName` 'slide-down' happens.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I managed to do this.
I'm using a normal event which I update then with the animationName that I need.

```
const animationEventMixin = (animationName: string) => ({ animationName });

...

const event = new Event("animationend");
Object.assign(event, animationEventMixin("slide-down"));
dispatchEvent(event);
```